# onChange Button label doesn't hold its style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, styles

I have an interesting problem. I have a button that is used for selecting (like a select item). That code is here:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" style="width: 166%;" 
        type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" 
        aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
   <span id="dropdown_button" style="width: 166%;">
     <img src="wp-content/themes/directory2/images/closest.png" />
          10 Closest Amenities</span>
   <span class="caret" style="margin-top: 9px;float: right;"></span>
</button>
```

Then it uses some jquery to change the text in the button/select like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.dropdown_anchor', function(event) {
    var index = $(this).data('index');
    var title = $(this).data('title');
    populate_list(index);
    dropdownButtonText(title);
});
```

Then the dropdownButtonText function is implemented as below:

```
function dropdownButtonText(text) {
    $("#dropdown_button").text(text);
}
```

The problem is, that the button spans the width it needs to on page load (aka `style="width: 166%;"`) but when the selection happens and its changed, the button then doesn't hold its set width. Meaning for example it goes from 166% to say 87% width.

How can I make it so that the button holds its width when changed?

Thank you for your input and time, it's appreciated.

An example can be seen here:
https://www.trustedlivingcare.com/item/cedarhurst-of-sparta-il/

The Neighborhood & Nearby Amenities area

**Starting Position**
https://www.screencast.com/t/TiuWZdhYcWc

**After Change**
https://www.screencast.com/t/goYgVtvrErW5

Comment: Can you make a snippet to demonstrate the problem?  Changing the text won't change the width *unless* the original text was wider than the width allowed and it forced the element to expand to fit (based on other css properties).

Comment: @freedomn-m I added a link to an example page so you can see it.

Comment: a) external sites are no use for historical reasons b) I have no idea on that page which is causing the problem

Comment: I just added two screen shots so you can see

Comment: There is no dropdown_anchor class in your code

Answer (score 0):

You can try grabbing the elements width before the text change:

```
 $(document).on('click', '.dropdown_anchor', function(event) {
          var index = $(this).data('index');
          var title = $(this).data('title');
          var width = $(this).outerWidth();
          populate_list(index);
          dropdownButtonText(title, width);
      });
```

and then apply that width in the new function.

```
 function dropdownButtonText(text, width) {
    $("#dropdown_button").css("width", width).text(text);
  }
```

The button will need to be display inline-block, though.

Comment: If you're using jQuery, you can use outerWidth (edited above).

Comment: That seems to get the outerwidth of the words, not the button

Comment: Then you need to get the width of the button. Change

`var width = $(this).outerWidth();`

to

`var width = $("#dropdown_button").outerWidth();`

Answer (score 0):

It is because the width of the button changes when the text has less characters than previous one. you can give the button a specific width in css so it doesn't change when the text change.

```
#dropdown_button {
width: 100px; // this is an example
}
```

You can also do min-width to make sure that is the least width the button goes.

```
#dropdown_button {
    min-width: 100px; // this is an example
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this in your css file

```
.btn-primary {
   min-width: 500px;
 }
```

Comment: That modifies the toggle on load, but doesn't do anything after it's been changed.

Comment: bro, i edited my answer. just try this and tell me did it worked

Answer (score 0):

Below what I have tried.

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button id="btnTest" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" style="width: 80%;">Dropdown Example
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul id="demolist" class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#btnTest').click(function() {
   console.log("Test");
});
$('#demolist li').on('click', function(){
    var selectedText = $(this).text();
    console.log(selectedText);
    $("#btnTest").html(selectedText+'&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span></button>');
});
</script>
```

Also, consult the demonstration at [using Bootstrap 3 Dropdown toggle button](https://jsfiddle.net/nvntung/59uxsbq2/7/)